# How to animate images using bitmaps / rgb data in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm programming a game on my iPhone, and I have an image I want to animate, say a walking person in a bitmap. The bitmap changes over time. How do I add the bitmaps to the screen/UIView efficiently?

Comment: Using a UIImageView with its animation capability (holding multiple, addressable images) seems to be the most trivial and in this way right solution.

Comment: The only problem with using UIImageView animation is that it has to load all of the animation frames in memory at once. This the problem that my GLImageView is designed to solve. Of course, you can stream ordinary PNGs or JPEGs into memory using a thread and writing your own timer-based animation code, but it's complex to set up, and you probably won't get 30FPS, especially on older devices.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to load an image sequence is to use PVR-format images and load them as OpenGL textures. PVR images support a variety of formats, including raw 32-bit RGB data.

I've wrapped up this functionality in a library that gives you a GLImageView and lets you specify a list of filenames which it will efficiently stream into memory and play in sequence:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/GLView

Check out the included example and see if it will work for your needs. The documentation includes instructions for creating the images in the right format, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a CAKeyframeAnimation.

I just wrote this and didn't test it - but should get you on the right path. Load all your frames into an NSArray then set the 'values' of the animation to the frames array.

```
NSArray *walkFrames = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"walk.00000.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"walk.00001.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"walk.00002.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"walk.00003.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"walk.00004.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"walk.00005.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"walk.00006.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"walk.00007.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"walk.00008.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"walk.00009.png"],
           nil] retain];

CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];

anim.keyPath = @"contents";
anim.duration = 2.f;
anim.values = walkFrames;
anim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;

[myView addAnimation:anim forKey:@"myFlipAnimation"];
```

Comment: What I meant in the question was to use rgbdata for images and upload them to the screen quickly

Comment: This is the most efficient way to animate a flipbook style animation (which is what you are asking how to do). The PNG images of course are RGB data. Can you explain better?

Comment: If you're going to do that, why not just use the animationImages property of UIImageView?

Comment: I suppose there are always a number of ways to skin a cat. ;)