# Issue In generating a Video from array of images

Tags: iphone, video, avassetwriter

I'm trying to generate the video from the array of images stored in the resource folder of my project..I use this code to generate the video...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    imagearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Quiz pic1.jpg",@"Quiz pic2.jpg",@"Quiz pic3.jpg",@"Quiz pic6.jpg",@"Quiz pic7.jpg",nil];
    image1array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<[imagearray count]; i++)
    {
        UIImage *aimage=[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [image1array addObject:aimage];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",image1array);
    ImageVideoPath=@"/Users/image/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/6CC91208-5819-4BFF-B868-6605887861EB/Output";
    FinalVideoPath=@"/Users/image/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/6CC91208-5819-4BFF-B868-6605887861EB/VideoOutput";
    CGSize size;
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:0]];
    size=image.size;
    NSString *audioFilePath;
    int duration=10;
    //[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[image1array objectAtIndex:0] CGImage]];
    [self writeImageAndAudioAsMovie:image andAudio:audioFilePath duration:duration];

    //[self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[image CGImage] andSize:size];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)writeImageAndAudioAsMovie:(UIImage*)image andAudio:(NSString *)audioFilePath duration:(int)duration {
    NSLog(@"start make movie: length:%d",duration);
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:ImageVideoPath] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                              error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:ImageVideoPath]) 
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:ImageVideoPath error:nil];

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:image.size.width],AVVideoWidthKey,[NSNumber numberWithInt:image.size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,nil];
    AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                        assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                        outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
    NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
    writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    [videoWriter setShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse:YES];
    [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    for (int i=0; i<[image1array count]; i++)
{
    int time = (int)i*(duration/[image1array count]);
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[[image1array objectAtIndex:i] CGImage]];
    [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(time, 1)];
}

    //Finish the session:
    [videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(duration, 1)];
    [writerInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWriting];

    CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);
    [videoWriter release];
    [writerInput release];
    audioFilePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Video" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSLog(@"%@",audioFilePath);
    [self addAudioToFileAtPath:ImageVideoPath andAudioPath:audioFilePath];
}

-(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image{
    float width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    float height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width,height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,(CFDictionaryRef)options,&pxbuffer);

    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata,width,height,8,4*width,rgbColorSpace,kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    NSParameterAssert(context);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0,width, height), image);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

I found that some file is created once I run tat code ,bt itz nt supporting any players in my machine..
I don't knw wat I'm missing here..Any Suggestions to make my code to work...

Comment: Did you get the answer to your problem??? as i have got the mistake in it

Comment: S .... Very simple while saving the file in a path it should me saved with proper extension name (.mp4 r .mp3)

Comment: Yes that is what i found..any ways is this code correct one??as i am also trying to change image array to video..will you help me in that please??

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you actually want to convert the images to a video? Why not animate the images itself to mimic a video. The way cartoon are made? IT would be something like so -

```
NSArray *animImages  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SodaPour1" ofType:@"png"]],
                        [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SodaPour39" ofType:@"png"]],
                        nil];

imgGlass.animationImages = GlassAnim;
imgGlass.animationDuration = 2.5;
imgGlass.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imgGlass.animationRepeatCount=1;
[GlassAnim release];
```

also you can check this - [How to animate images using bitmaps / rgb data in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959651/how-to-animate-images-using-bitmaps-rgb-data-in-ios)

Comment: Thanks...Yes I wanna to convert the images to video and I don't wanna to animate it...

Comment: why u want to convert to video? animating the images will give you the same effect...

Comment: My app is abt generating a video and upload tat to facebook..So animating images won't sounds gud in tat case...

Comment: I have given the full sample code for creating video with audio.Please go through the code.If you have any problem .let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- 1st mention the path for  video,audio and final video path

*

```
- (IBAction)makeMovieButtonTouchUpInside:(id)sender {
if (selectedImageArray.count == 0) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"please select at least one image" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
    return;
}
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"30secs" ofType:@"mp3"];

NSString *videoPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test_output.mp4"]];

NSString *finalVideoFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"final_video.mp4"];

UIImage *img = [selectedImageArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"h:%@,w:%@",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:img.size.height],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:img.size.width]);

[self writeImageAndAudioAsMovie:img andVideoPath:videoPath andAudio:audioFilePath andFinalVideoPath:finalVideoFilePath duration:30];
```

}

- Write the video file

*

```
NSLog(@"start make movie: length:%d",duration);
NSError *error = nil;

AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];

NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:videoPath]){//ImageVideoPath
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:videoPath error:nil];
}

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:image.size.width],AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:image.size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];

AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                   assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                   outputSettings:videoSettings];

AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
[videoWriter setShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse:YES];
[videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

//Start a session:
[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

NSUInteger fps = 30;

int frameCount = 0;
double numberOfSecondsPerFrame = 6;
double frameDuration = fps * numberOfSecondsPerFrame;

for(UIImage * img in selectedImageArray)
{
    buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage]];

    BOOL append_ok = NO;
    int j = 0;
    while (!append_ok && j < 30) {
        if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)  {
            //print out status:
            NSLog(@"Processing video frame (%d,%d)",frameCount,[imageArray count]);

            CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount*frameDuration,(int32_t) fps);
            append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
            if(!append_ok){
                NSError *error = videoWriter.error;
                if(error!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@.", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
        }
        j++;
    }
    if (!append_ok) {
        printf("error appending image %d times %d\n, with error.", frameCount, j);
    }
    frameCount++;
}
//Finish the session:
[videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(60*8, 1)];//give a user defined duration and endthe session
[writerInput markAsFinished];
NSURL *refURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath];
[videoArray addObject:refURL];

//get the iOS version of the device
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if (version < 6.0){
    [videoWriter finishWriting];
    NSLog (@"finished writing iOS version:%f",version);
} else {
    [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^(){
        NSLog (@"finished writing iOS version:%f",version);
    }];
}
CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);
[self addAudioToFileAtPath:audioFilePath toVideoPath:videoPath andFinalVideoPath:finalVideoPath];
```

}

Utility Method for pixel Buffer from Image
*

```
     - (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image{

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                    CGImageGetHeight(image), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                    &pxbuffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                             CGImageGetHeight(image), 8, 4*CGImageGetWidth(image), rgbColorSpace,
                                             (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));


CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                       CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

return pxbuffer;
```

}

- Add AudioFile to video

**

```
-(void) addAudioToFileAtPath:(NSString *) audiofilePath toVideoPath:(NSString       
*)videoFilePath andFinalVideoPath:(NSString *)finalVideoPath
 {
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

// audio input file...
NSURL    *audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audiofilePath];

// this is the video file that was just written above, full path to file is in --> videoOutputPath
NSURL    *video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilePath];

// create the final video output file as MOV file - may need to be MP4, but this works so far...
NSURL    *outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalVideoPath];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:finalVideoPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:finalVideoPath error:nil];

CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];

CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);

AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

//nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);

AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];

CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);

AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
//_assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
_assetExport.outputFileType = @"public.mpeg-4";
//NSLog(@"support file types= %@", [_assetExport supportedFileTypes]);
_assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {
     switch (_assetExport.status)
     {
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
             //                export complete
             NSLog(@"Export Complete");
             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
             NSLog(@"Export Failed");
             NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
             //                export error (see exportSession.error)
             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
             NSLog(@"Export Failed");
             NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
             //                export cancelled
             break;
     }
     //If you want to save the video to Photo Album
     UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (finalVideoPath,self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
 }
 ];

///// THAT IS IT DONE... the final video file will be written here...
NSLog(@"DONE.....outputFilePath--->%@", finalVideoPath);

// the final video file will be located somewhere like here:
// /Users/caferrara/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/D4B12FEE-E09C-4B12-B772-7F1BD6011BE1/Documents/outputFile.mov
```

}

**

- Show an alert for succesful video creation

**
  - (void)video:(NSString *) videoPath didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error
   contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo
   {
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

```
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError   
*error){
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Video could not be saved ,Error:%@",error);
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry!!" message:@"Video data is Nil" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];

    }else{
        if (![videoArray containsObject:url]) {
            [videoArray addObject:url];
        }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                   message:@"Movie succesfully exported."
                                                  delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    }
}];
```

}**