# Can I animate with use multiple images instead of one?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

Using core graphics, I am moving my image over a predefined path.

I would like to use multiple images instead of one in order to achieve animation.
Can anyone tell me how to achieve this(using multiple images instead of one)?

This my code with single image:

```
bounceLayer = [CALayer layer];
bounceLayer.frame = CGRectMake(12, 12, 12, 12);
[bounceLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(175.0f, 100.0f)];  

bounceLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:
                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Avatar_%d.png",i]].CGImage;
 [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:bounceLayer];
 [bounceLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(120.0f, 49.0f)];
 [bounceLayer addAnimation:[self bounceAnimationPathWithDuration:3.0f] forKey:nil];
```

bounceAnimationPathWithDuration - is a function which creates a path

Is this possible with Core graphics? or should I use Cocoa 2D?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how exactly you're using images to achieve animation? Is this an image sequence?

Comment: also,please try accept some answers for the questions you have already asked.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can use multiple images instead of one in order to achieve animation. The way cartoon are made. You can even use Bezier Curves to make different images in your animation take a certain path. It would be something like so -

```
NSArray *animImages  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SodaPour1" ofType:@"png"]],
                        [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SodaPour39" ofType:@"png"]],
                        nil];

imgGlass.animationImages = GlassAnim;
imgGlass.animationDuration = 2.5;
imgGlass.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imgGlass.animationRepeatCount=1;
[GlassAnim release];
```

also you can check this - [How to animate images using bitmaps / rgb data in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959651/how-to-animate-images-using-bitmaps-rgb-data-in-ios)

Comment: Hi Srikar,  Thx for your help. I will try and let u know. Many Thx.

Comment: Srikar,  Sorry for asking this dumb question may be...
Can u tell me how can I relate your suggestion to replace this line of code and hence I load multiple images to my Layer rather than just one...

bounceLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"].CGImage;

Comment: My question was, how can I relate your suggestion to replace this line of code and hence I load multiple images to my Layer rather than just one... bounceLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"].CGImage;